# Contradiction Problem

Tags: number-theory

Question:

There are 101 buttons of up to 11 different colors in a box. Show that either there are 11 buttons of the same color in the box or there are 11 buttons all in different colors in the box.

I understand that we need to assume the initial condition where there are buttons of 11 different colours but what would our implication be? I am not sure how to show a contradiction.

Comment: To show a contradiction you assume the *negation* of the statement you wish to prove.  Start by writing down the negation of what you wish to prove and go from there.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax in the future to assist those trying to help you. Also after keying in your question but before hitting post, check the side bar to see if there are duplicates or similar problems that can help answer your question. In this case, I think you misunderstand what you think you "understand."   What you need to assume is the contradiction of one possibility and use that to prove that the other possibility holds.

Answer (score 0):

If there fewer than 11 colors of button, and fewer than 11 buttons of each color, we can maximally fit 100 buttons in the box.

Answer (score 0):

If there are at most $10$ different colors and at most $10$ buttons of each color, that is at most $100$ buttons.

As there are $101$ then if there are no more than $10$ of each color there must be at least $\lceil \frac {101}{10} \rceil = 11$ different colors.

And if there were no more than $10$ colors there must be at least $\lceil \frac {101}{10}\rceil = 11$ in at least one group of colors.